# Excel get set of values from a column based on list choice

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a excel grid with following structure:

[image]

IN cell Y2 (Choose) there is a list with the text of the cells of V3, W3 and X3(TIC2, LP3 and MAT4).

I want based on the users choice in cell Y2, the range of cells (Y3:Y13) to be populated with the respective values of the column with that name. For example, If the users chooses LP3 it should fill Y3 to Y13 withe the values present in column W3:W13.

I know how to use VLOOKUP for a value, but this is different.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Y3 put:

```
=INDEX(V3:X3,MATCH($Y$2,$V$3:$X$3,0))
```

And copy down.

Or you can use an HLOOKUP:

```
=HLOOKUP($Y$2,$V$3:$X$1040000,ROW()-2,FALSE)
```

Again, put that in Y3 and copy down.

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thank you very much!!